# Puppeteer not executing forEach

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I have this code

```
  ...
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  page.on('console', msg => {
    if (msg._type === 'log') {
      console.log(msg._text);
    }
  });
  ...

  await page.evaluate(() => {
    document.querySelectorAll('.foo').forEach(bar => {
      console.log('This logs not');
      if (bar.querySelector('div > p').innerHTML === 'foo bar') {
        bar.querySelector('.dropdown').click();
      }
    });
  });
```

But its not logging anything. When I do

```
  await page.evaluate(() => {
    const test = document.querySelectorAll('.foo')
    console.log('This logs');
    test.forEach(bar => {
      console.log('This logs not');
      if (bar.querySelector('div > p').innerHTML === 'foo bar') {
        bar.querySelector('.dropdown').click();
      }
    });
  });
```

It logs the first `console.log()`.
Why isn#t it executing the `forEach`?

Comment: I ran some test code (browsing StackOverflow and getting anchors) and it worked for me. Your selector might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelectorAll('.foo')` is empty because there is no element with that selector. That's why you are not getting any result when it's logging.

[image]

Comment: When I perform it in the console inn the browser, its not empty. I get a `NodeList`

Comment: You should share rest of your code or the website/page. Maybe it's not finished loading when you are running it on puppeteer.

Comment: I wait for the page to load with `await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'load' });`

Comment: That's where the problem lies. You must use `networkidle0` instead of `load` and my answer will be perfect for your problem :D